# mysql query not working in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

```
UPDATE `mytable` SET `status`='og' WHERE `my_date_time` < now()
```

The above given query is working perfectly when fired in phpmyadmin but not working in codeigniter.
This is how I'm trying to do it in codeigniter:

```
$this->db->set('status','og');
$this->db->where('my_date_time <','NOW()');
$this->db->update('mytable');
```

All my other mysql queries are working fine through codeigniter.

Comment: $date = new DateTime("now");
     $curr_date = $date->format('Y-m-d');
     $data=array('status'=>'og');
     $this->db->where('my_date_time <',$curr_date);
     $this->db->update('mytable',$data);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this query for your problem :

```
$this->db->set('status','og');
$this->db->where('my_date_time < NOW()',false);
$this->db->update('mytable');
```

Comment: It worked! Thanks. But can you please explain me about this thrid parameter?

Comment: you can visit this link for where clause in codeigniter URL : https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html

Comment: I read it. It says 'If you set it to FALSE, CodeIgniter will not try to protect your field or table names'. What does this exactly mean? Can you give an example situation?